# Create visits without internet in the application

Tags: mobile, sync, offline

When a visit is created from the offline application, it's created without problem but it is not possible to execute the visit, I'm a developer and I found a previous event that takes place (see in image), if the result is not one the visit is loaded in any other case it shows the following message:

**The new visit cannot be opened due to missing data. Please wait for the synchronisation process to complete.**

[image]

Is it possible to create an offline visit and run it without synchronization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not feasible to execute the visit without synchronizing first. After creating the visit, it's essential to sync it so that the visit data can be stored in the system. Without this synchronization, the system lacks the necessary visit data to execute the visit properly.